# PDOException could not find driver"

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, xampp

I have XAMPP installed on my PC. when I am entering php artisan migrate:install on terminal error comes " [PDOException] could not find driver" now what can I do. answers here given using apache2. what can I do in Xampp.

Answer (score 0):

This is a PHP error, not a phpMyAdmin error. Check the PHP.ini configuration to make sure that the `php_pdo_mysql` extension is enabled.

The line in the PHP configuration file should look like this:

```
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
```